# how to store the image name without the path - laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, eloquent

What is the right way to store my images to database

should I store the fill path of the image like so `images/pagesImages/image.jpg` or the right way is store only the image name and write the path where the image should appear?

I am new to Laravel and I am updating image on the page when I updated the image I found that the full path was stored on the database

can I store only the image name without the path?

here is my controller

```
public function editAboutImage()
    {
        $id = 1;
        $image = Text_area::find($id);

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,png|min:1|max:250'
        ]);

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('edit-about')->with('errors', $validation->errors());
        }
        if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
            $file = Input::file('image');
            $destination_path = 'images/pagesImages/';
            $filename = str_random(6) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destination_path, $filename);
            $image->image = $destination_path . $filename;
            $image->save();
        }
        return Redirect::to('edit-about')->with('message', 'You just updated an image!');
    }
```

clarify my two questions

1. which is the better way to store images should I store it with path or just the image name.
2. if I need to store the image name only without the path what should I do with my controller.

many thanks

Comment: just the image name will be better.

Comment: Personally i just save the image name.  Unless you have images on various directory, I can't think of any advantage on saving the whole path.  I don't understand 2nd question.

Comment: @Sanzeeb Aryal thanks I thought the same, can you help edit the controller above to store the image name only

Comment: `$image->image = $destination_path . $filename;` should be `$image->image = $filename;`

Comment: @cjmling thanks for the advice the second question is about my controller how can I edit it to store my image name only without the path? thanks

Comment: nothing much you should do. `$image->image = $filename;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Just store image name only. Because, if you are going to changing the path, then you can easily get by file name. If also changing the file to new path.
2. You can use your model to simply store the file (my suggestion)

   in your model, create one variable and one function to store image
   For model:-

   ```
    public static $imagePath = 'images/profile_images';       

    public function getImageAttribute($value)       
    {
       if($value != ''){
           return self::getImagePath . '.' . $value;
       }
    }

    public function getImagePath()       
    {
           return self::imagePath;
    }
   ```

   For controller:-

   get as usual file name,
   At the storage

   ```
   $file->move($this->getImagePath(), $filename);        
   $image->image = $filename;
   ```

   Try this and said result

Comment: what i can't inderstand

Comment: i use this code in my project. So you can use this and try.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very late answer but for those that come accross it.
When you call the store method

```
$request->file('image')->store('',YourBaseFolderName);
```

This will save the folder in the folder you want, for example public/images,
would be

```
$request->file('image')->store('','images');
```

and only the file name would be returned